# Derivation of Maclaurin Series of arcsin x

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

Consider the function of $f$ defined by$$f(x) = \arcsin x, for \space  \vert x \vert \le 1.$$The derivatives of $f(x)$ satisfy the equation$$(1-x^2)f^{(n+2)}(x)-(2n+1)xf^{(n+1)}(x)-n^2f^{(n)}(x)=0, for \space n \ge 1.$$ The coefficient of $x^n$ in the Maclaurin Series for $f(x)$ is denoted by $a_n$. You may assume that the series contains only odd powers of $x$.

I am interested in how to prove that the derivatives of $\arcsin x$ satisfy the above differential equation?

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**:

$$f(x)=\arcsin x.$$
Differentiating,
$$f'(x)=\frac1{\sqrt{1-x^2}},\\\sqrt{1-x^2}f'(x)=1.$$
Differentiating again,
$$\sqrt{1-x^2}f''(x)-\frac x{\sqrt{1-x^2}}f'(x)=0,\\(1-x^2)f''(x)-xf'(x)=0.$$

Now you can apply the Leibnitz rule to evaluate the next derivatives. As the left factors are polynomials, you will end up with five terms of the form

$$(1-x^2)f^{(n+2)},-2xf^{(n+1)},2f^{(n)},\text{ and }-xf^{(n+1)},-f^{(n)},$$ weighted by binomial coefficients. After simplification, the claim will hold.